# Git operations from Android studio fail

Tags: git, android-studio

I'm recently hit with a weird issue where my android studio craps out everytime I trigger any git operation (like pull/push). It says:

```
Update failed
        Invocation failed Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Invocation failed Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
        at org.jetbrains.git4idea.nativessh.GitNativeSshAskPassXmlRpcClient.handleInput(GitNativeSshAskPassXmlRpcClient.java:34)
        at org.jetbrains.git4idea.nativessh.GitNativeSshAskPassApp.main(GitNativeSshAskPassApp.java:30)
        Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unexpected Response from Server:  Unauthorized
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendRequest(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:231)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.LiteXmlRpcTransport.sendXmlRpc(LiteXmlRpcTransport.java:90)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClientWorker.execute(XmlRpcClientWorker.java:72)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:194)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:185)
        at org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcClient.execute(XmlRpcClient.java:178)
        at org.jetbrains.git4idea.nativessh.GitNativeSshAskPassXmlRpcClient.handleInput(GitNat... (show balloon)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Previously, it used to say "RSA host key for IP address 'x.x.x.x' not in list of known hosts'. I deleted known_hosts file and command_line git asked me if it can create one and add this IP, and I said yes.

Command line doesn't have any problem running git operations. It's sourceTree and Android studio who have the problem and I don't know why

Answer (score 1):

When the remote `known_hosts` knows the client's IP, the remote host likely cannot be associated locally, or for some other reason, the SSH2 authentication doesn't succeed. `Unauthorized` generally means, that the firewall isn't the problem.

Try to use the "native" client - which should work, while it works in the terminal:

[image]

Comment: It's set to Native already. But changing that value to Built-In worked and I don't know why